# Yammer embed open-graph feed for object, not an url?

Tags: embed, yammer

Is it possible to create an open-graph url for object which is not a www url? Like for network drive location for example?

I tried it and the embed feed seems to only load for www urls.

Here are my questions:

Is it possible to not use a normal www url for the object?

Where is the documentation what different config options are available for the open-graph?

Where is the documentation for the objectProperties config? I'd like to provide all of them manually and disable the system which tries to fetch them through embed.ly or what ever.

This works fine:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "m-files.com",
    feedType: "open-graph",
    objectProperties: {
        url: "https://www.microsoft.com",
        type:  "file",
        title: "Yammer.pdf"
    }
});
```

But for example this doesn't:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "m-files.com",
    feedType: "open-graph",
    objectProperties: {
        url: "\\192.168.1.8\Something\somefile.pdf",
        type:  "file",
        title: "Yammer.pdf"
    }
});
```

Comment: I really don't think that would work, but you might want to try the syntax for a URL, e.g., smb://server/path/file, not a UNC, e.g., \\server\path\file

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.. it seems that Yammer OG objects accept only http or https urls. Have to try to make some proxy page which redirects to correct protocol / address based on query string parameters.

Comment: I did a little research and it turns out this isn't possible. Yammer uses embed.ly to index non-Yammer content. See https://developer.yammer.com/opengraph/#og-embedly for more info. But if Yammer doesn't know about it and embed.ly doesn't know about it you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think it's because of embed.ly. You can use private network urls for the og object too and can provide all the open graph data in the object properties. But the url is a required parameter and it only accepts urls in http or https protocols. It doesn't have to be publicly available though.